# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory but directory is true

Tags: php, require

I have a project file, and is simple stucture

```
home/index.php
     folder_1/file1.php
     folder_2/file2.php
```

if in file1.php i use "require('../index.php');" and it's work,
but why i can't use a same sytax at file2.php?

it's a error :

```
[01-Feb-2017 03:02:58 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(../index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/lingga/public_html/folder_1/file1.php on line 2
[01-Feb-2017 03:02:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '../index.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in /home/lingga/public_html/administrator/php/config/aplication-pack.php on line 2
```

Comment: you need to use full path in require because it start from root

Comment: @AkkapongKajornwongwattana ...? Only the end folder requires permission, not the full path.

Comment: i have try to start from root , "require("/home/{my_username}/www/index.php");" but is not working, please use other way..??

Comment: can you change file permission to 755?

Comment: yes, i try it but not working, have a new way?

Comment: thanks, this trouble is wrong the config of server at include_path, sorry all